# How to get every valid hex code in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, underscore.js

This a little thing that i started at work two days ago thinking it would be a quick little brain problem then ill get back to eating my lunch. However im struggling. I want to get an array of all valid hexadecimal color codes. Without crashing the browser preferably.

This is what i came up with so far.

```
app.directive 'randomColor', () ->
  link: (scope) ->
    scope.colors = new Array
    col = 0x0
    while col <= 0xFFF
      if (col > 0x111 && col < 0xFFF)
        scope.colors.push '#' + col
      col++
    autocolor = (hexcode) ->
      colorChange = () ->
        $("#colorvomit").append("<span style='padding: 1px 10px 1px 10px;background-color: " +hexcode+";border: 1px solid black;'></span>")
      setTimeout(colorChange, 5000)
    _.each(scope.colors, autocolor)
```

Bare in mind im using coffescript and angular js. With the underscore library so i can use _.each.

So i get this as the result

[image]

you can see there are a lot of white squares at the bottom and it goes on forever a long time because it comes back with invalid hex codes like #1223 (4 digit ones).

So here is my question what is the best way to get all valid hexadecimal color codes lets say 6 long i have 3 long (FFF) because it crashes otherwise without getting invalid codes. Appreciate all your help and i think this would be a fun question to ask.

I have done my research and cant find anything similar. Because we want them all preferably in order as well like 111 112 113 ect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have this in mind that 256*256*256 = 16777216 so it will take sometime to execute.

```
var result = '';
for(var i=0;i<256;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<256;j++)
        for(var k=0;k<256;k++)
           {r = i.toString(16);
           g = j.toString(16);
           b = k.toString(16);
             if(r.length!=1||g.length!=1||b.length!=1){
        if(r.length==1)r='0'+r;
        if(g.length==1)g='0'+g;
        if(b.length==1)b='0'+b;
        }//will use 3 length color unless one of r,g or b is to digit then 6 length will be used.
            result += r + g + b + '<br/>';
        }

document.write(result);
```

If you want it in array then:

```
var result = [];
for(var i=0;i<256;i+=16)
    for(var j=0;j<256;j+=16)
        for(var k=0;k<256;k+=16)
           {r = i.toString(16);
           g = j.toString(16);
           b = k.toString(16);
            if(r.length!=1||g.length!=1||b.length!=1){
            if(r.length==1)r='0'+r;
            if(g.length==1)g='0'+g;
            if(b.length==1)b='0'+b;
            } //will use 3 length color unless one of r,g or b is to digit then 6 length will be used.
            result.push(r + g + b);
        }
```

See the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g75s9exc/1/)

Here is a Graphical [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g75s9exc/2/) with reduced number of colors as we can not show millions of colors.

Comment: Is it not cheating because we want and array of hex codes. Not to use RGB codes. Also i'm probably wrong here but might that code not miss out some colors.

Comment: well this code generates hex code. I just have used r, g, and b variables to make the code meaningful

Comment: @Morphasis, when I was correcting my code I had removed some of the code by mistake. I just corrected it.

Comment: Hi there im just going to boot this up and test it it will be interesting to see it looks good lets see if it ever runs :)

Comment: I have already created a demo:  (https://jsfiddle.net/g75s9exc/1/)[https://jsfiddle.net/g75s9exc/1/]

Comment: Thats awesome man thanks so much for your help. Im just reading through the answers learning from them now your solutions have been great ! thanks once again.

Comment: @Morphasis remember that you can not just show millions of colors like that you just have to take some of them

Comment: I added a new demo with some graphics check it

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a nested loop, I just converted decimal from/to hex. Not better, just different. Fiddle below, showing operation.

*Edit: This code is modified to run all 16 million colors. The fiddle still uses 8 bit per color (`#000;` brief notation), so that it won't take forever to run

```
var $cv= $("#colorvomit");
for(var col=parseInt("000000", 16); col<=parseInt("ffffff", 16); col++) {
    var hex = col.toString(16);
  hex = '0'.repeat(6-hex.length) + hex;
    $cv.append('<span style="background-color:#'+hex+';"> &nbsp; </span>');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4tm54u62/1/

Comment: This is super cool and just what i want to achieve is there a way to use a 6 hex code with this.

Comment: Ahh i got it running sorry i had to give the answer to the other dude before he was first and also correct. But your solution is more along the display i want to throw out i want to thank you once again its really helpful.

Comment: No problem, totally understand. Also, modified my answer to show how to modify for complete 16 bit per color results, and to include the full 0x000 through 0xfff range. Fiddle still shows 8 bit...takes too long in 16 bit.